# Class 'Facebook\GraphObject' not found with Facebook PHP SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I want to connect my page with facebook and downloaded therefore the [Facebook PHP SDK 4](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4). Since the Facebook documentation and the GitHub page are not really well made, I have a question regarding my error message from the title.

I don't want to use `Composer` for PHP (which should be possible according to the Facebook documentation).

I followed the example on the Github page and included the Facebook PHP files into my PHP file with the following lines of code:

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
```

In the documentation there is nowhere mentioned that I have to include the `require_once` statement, I found that on `stackoverflow`.

Problem is now that even with the above (correct) implementation, I get an error which says 'Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\GraphObject' not found in ../fblogin2/Facebook/GraphUser.php on line 33'

I think in this class there is also no `require_once` statement, but I can't go through the whole SDK code and add the statements for Facebook. Shouldn't it work out-of-the-box? Are there some good tutorials for the SDK 4 or anything else, because I'm really stuck with the official facebook documentation and the short github example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I found a good tutorial and solution for the Facebook SDK (v4) [here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).

It's 'funny' that a billion dollar company is not able to provide a decent documentation.

Comment: If you don't understand how including files and classes works in PHP I would suggest studying http://www.php.net and not blaming Facebook.

Comment: Yeah, now I understand it, but guess what? It's still a bad documentation. And btw it's nowhere documented which subclasses should be included.

Comment: That is why you use composer of another auto loader